# Suggestion on how to manage pagenotes in memoir

Tags: memoir, footnotes, pagenote

I posted a long question before, and it was suggested that I should split it into separate chunks, so here it is.

I wrote a book using the memoir class. It has about three hundreds notes and references, plus a substantial bibliography.

I have a very varied mix of notes and references, sometimes it's an article from a newspaper, sometimes a publication on a scientific journal, sometimes it's an old book, sometimes there is no external reference, and it's just me explaining something a little more in depth.

I wanted to have a list of notes at the end of the book, divided by chapters. So, after reading the documentation I decided to use the `\pagenote` command, and then add `\let\pagenote=\endnote` before the beginning of the document.

I got something satisfactory out of it, but I'm not convinced that I'm doing things properly. For example, there should be a proper order for the name of the author, the source, the link, etc... given by the system, not by hand.

Given the circumstances, what do you think is the best way to manage all of those links, references, and footnotes?

THis is what it looks like right now.

[image: The Notes as the look like now]

Comment: Late comment, but this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67389822/how-to-specify-the-font-in-an-endnote/67390258?noredirect=1#comment119127381_67390258

Answer (score 3):

Consider using the endheads package with memoir. It's worked pretty well for me with long documents of book length. J  Lehmke suggested a fix  for a  problem with the current version of memoir, and the author, J. Burt, has updated the package. I've mainly used it for placing endnotes at the end of a book, by chapter. I like the style of having the endnotes associated with the page on which it occurs. You can also place endnotes at the end of each chapter, or end of each page.

```
\documentclass[openany,oldfontcommands]{memoir}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{endheads} % requires oldfontcommands option for memoir class    
    \setupendnoteheaders 
    \titleinnotestrue  % title page
    \setstyleforchapternotebegin{\begin{flushleft}\begin{bf}\normalsize}
    \setstyleforchapternoteend{\end{bf}\end{flushleft}}
\begin{document}
\chapter{One}
\resetendnotes
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
The Higgs particle is still elusive. \endnote{chap 1, footnote 1}
\chapter{Two}
\resetendnotes
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
Travel near speed of light for a few years. Return. Poof. No more relationship problems.
\endnote{First footnote of chap 2. Second footnote of book}
Family and childhood friends will be scarce. \endnote{chap2, footnote 2}
\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{} \the\notescontentsname}
\theendnotes
\end{document}
```

[image: endnotes at end of document]

Comment: I tried the MWE above, and it gives me an error. What I am missing?


     /usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/endheads/endheads.sty:131: Class memoir Error: Undefined pagestyle '', so I cannot change it.